# federated table error when GTID is ON for Mysql replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysql-5.7, federated, gtid

I have an issue on mysql replication.

I have master, slave and another independent db, and enforce_gtid_consistency = ON on master and slave.

my test case:

```
BEGIN;
USE demo;
INSERT INTO demo.log_master(msg)value('demo2');
CALL sp_log_independent('test14');
ROLLBACK;
//commit
```

When I try to insert federated table in a transaction, It gives error like below.

```
mysql> call sp_log_independent('test14');
ERROR 1785 (HY000): Statement violates GTID consistency: Updates to non-transactional tables can only be done in either autocommitted statements or single-statement transactions, and never in the same statement as updates to transactional tables.
mysql>
```

I want to log all kind of things whether in a transaction or in a non-transaction. Can I exclude federated tables for replication ? or how to force it for replication ?

Comment: "or how to force it for replication ? " That would be counter intuitive because The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology

Comment: "Can I exclude federated tables for replication ?" seams it's explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-diffengines.html .. You don't need FEDERATED engine support on the slave to work with FEDERATED engine on the master.